# Laravel 8: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: laravel, webpack

I installed laravel 8 as follows:

```
laravel new my-project
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

I also post the files webpack.mix.js to package.json.

**Webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
}
```

After installing node_modules and activating the npm run dev command, following error appears:

```
Path must be a string. Received undefined <br />
D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\chat\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js <br />
Unexpected reserved word
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Post your webpack.mix.js file? And maybe your package.json file?

Comment: I posted the files

Comment: Sometimes things go dumb with no obvious reason. Try deleting `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file than repeat `npm install && npm run dev`.

Comment: I deleted node_modules folder and package-lock.json...and reinstall it using npm install && npm run dev...but I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After installing the latest node version (14.15.4), reinstalling the node modules, running the command `npm run dev` didn't give me any errors. Seems to be there are some dependencies in Laravel 8 to a certain node version. However, I didn't find any requirements on the Laravel official website.